# Design question around Spring Cloud Stream, Avro, Kafka and losing data along the way

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud, avro, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

We have implemented a system consisting of several Spring Boot microservices that communicate via messages posted to Kafka topics. We are using Spring Cloud Stream to handle a lot of the heavy lifting of sending and receiving messages via Kafka. We are using Apache Avro as a transport protocol, integrating with a Schema Server (Spring Cloud Stream default implementation for local development, and Confluent for production).

We model our message classes in a common library, that every micro service includes as a dependency. We use ‘dynamic schema generation’ to infer the Avro schema from the shape of our message classes before the Avro serialisation occurs when a microservice acts as a producer and sends a message. The consuming micro service can look up the schema from the registry based on the schema version and deserialise into the message class, which it also has as a dependency.

It works well, however there is one big drawback for us that I wonder if anyone has experienced before and could offer any advice. If we wish to add a new field for example to one of the model classes, we do it in the common model class library and update the of that dependency in the micro service. But it means that we need to update the version of that dependency in every micro service along the chain, even if the in-between micro services do not need that new field. Otherwise, the data value of that new field will be lost along the way, because of the way the micro service consumers deserialise into an object (which might be an out of date version of the class) along the way.

To give an example, lets say we have a model class in our model-common library called PaymentRequest (the @Data annotation is Lombok and juts generates getters and setters from the fields):

```
@Data 
class PaymentRequest {   
  String paymentId;   
  String customerId;
}
```

And we have a micro service called PayService which sends a PaymentRequest message onto Kafka topic:

```
  @Output("payment-broker”)
MessageChannel paymentBrokerTopic();
...
 PaymentRequest paymentRequest = getPaymentRequest();
 Message<PaymentRequest> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(paymentRequest).build();
paymentBrokerTopic().(message);
```

And we have this config in application.yaml in our Spring Boot application:

```
  spring:
   cloud:
    stream:
      schema-registry-client:
        endpoint: http://localhost:8071
      schema:
        avro:
          dynamicSchemaGenerationEnabled: true       bindings:
        Payment-broker:
          destination: paymentBroker
          contentType: application/*+avro
```

Spring Cloud Stream’s Avro MessageConverter infers the schema from the PaymentRequest object, adds a schema to the schema registry if there is not already a matching one there, and sends the message on Kafka in Avro format.  Then we have a consumer in another micro service, BrokerService, which has this consumer:

```
  @Output("payment-processor”)
MessageChannel paymentProcessorTopic();

  @Input(“payment-request”)
SubscribableChannel paymentRequestTopic();

 @StreamListener("payment-request")
public void processNewPayment(Message<PaymentRequest> request) {
   // do some processing and then send on…    
  paymentProcessorTopic().(message); 
}
```

It is able to deserialise that Avro message from Kafka into a PaymentRequest POJO, do some extra processing on it, and send the message onwards to another topic, which is called paymentProcessor, which then gets picked up by another micro service, called PaymentProcessor, which has another StreamListener consumer:

```
   @Input(“payment-processor”)
SubscribableChannel paymentProcessorTopic();

  @StreamListener("payment-processor”)
public void processNewPayment(Message<PaymentRequest> request) {
   // do some processing and action request… 
}
```

If we wish to update the PaymentRequest class in the model-common library, so that it has a new field:

```
@Data class PaymentRequest {   
  String paymentId;   
  String customerId;   
  String processorCommand; 
}
```

if we update the dependency version in each of the micro service, the value of that new field get deserialised into the field when the message is read, and reserialised into the message when it gets sent on to the next topic, each time.

However, if we do not update the version of model-common library in the second service in the chain. BrokerService, for example, it will deserialise the message into a version of the class without that new field, and so when the message is reserialised into a message sent on to the payment-processor topic the Avro message will not have the data for that field.

The third micro service, PaymentProcessor, might have the version of the model-common lib that does contain the new field, but when the message is deserialised into the POJO the value for that field will be null.

I know Avro has features for schema evolution where default values can be assigned for new fields to allow for backwards and forwards compatibility, but that is not sufficient for us here, we need the real values. And ideally we do not want a situation where we would have to update the dependency version of the model library in every micro service because that introduces a lot of work and coupling between services. Often a new field is not needed by the services midway along the chain, and only might be relevant in the first service and the final one for example.

So has anyone else faced this issue and thought of a good way round it? We are keen to not lose the power of Avro and the convenience of Spring Cloud Stream, but not have such dependency issues. Anything around custom serializers/deserializers we could try? Or using GenericRecords? Or an entirely different approach?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: In general, yes, you need to update your consumer api models in a backwards fashion down the processing pipeline if you expect the fields to be available for processing. It's not a unique problem to Kafka/Spring/Avro though. A GenericRecord would mitigate the need for dependency changes, but then you'd have to manage duplicate parsing logic across apps, as well as still have to update those individually for when new fields are needed to be accessed

Comment: Thanks a lot @OneCricketeer I appreciate the response! Pretty much confirms what I suspected.